# Find all matrices $A$ (if any) which commute with $C$ (Just need my work checked)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ c & d\\
\end{bmatrix},\;
C= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Here's my attempt:

$AC=CA,$

$AC=
\begin{bmatrix}
b & 0\\ d & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},\;
CA= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ a & b\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, $b=0, d=a$.

Did I approach this correctly? I know it probably seems fairly easy.

Comment: Yes, it looks correct.  From the phrasing of your solution, $b=0$ and $a=d$ are necessary conditions deduced from the two matrix products.  You should at least mention at some point that they are also sufficient to make all four entries identical.

Comment: @DougM Neither $A$ nor $C$ is diagonal in the general case, so I'm really not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DougM Noooo, any polynomial function of $C$ also commutes with $C$.  In this case $A$ is equal to an arbitrary linear function of $C$, namely $x\to ax + c$.

Comment: One way to interpret your (correct) answer: Under those conditions, $A=aI+cC$ where $I$ is the 2-by-2 identity matrix. But $C$ certainly commutes with both $I$ and itself, so it must also commute with $aI+cC$. By contrast, it doesn't commute with $C^T=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which shows up in $A$ if $b\neq 0$.

Comment: right right right.  Losing my mind.

Comment: @DougM Maybe you feel better, when I tell you that I thought that the entry $d$ in the product $AC$ would be in the first row and the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a correct method. If $b=0, d=a$ then they commute (as you've shown), and if they commute then these conditions hold. So this condition is necessary and sufficient.